# Two different google charts on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I initially had a columnchart on page1 and a linechart on page2. They both display fine when on their own page. When I try combine the two on one page, they both display but they both are columncharts. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. This is my code so far:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

function drawchart() {
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arm');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
  for (var i = 0; i < chartdatax.length; i++) {
      chartData.addRow([parseFloat(chartdatax[i]),
      parseFloat(chartdatay[i])]);
  };

   var options = {
       height: 500,
       hAxis: {
          title: 'Arm C.G',
          gridlines: {
            count: 10
        }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Weight',
          gridlines: {
            count: 10
        }
        },
      chartArea: {top:40, width: "70%", height: "75%"},
      animation:{
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out',
        startup: true,
      },
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      pointSize: 5
    };

   myLineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));

    myLineChart.draw(chartData, options);

}

function drawchart2(elevations, status) {
var chartDiv = document.getElementById('elevation_chart');
if (status !== google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
 // Show the error code inside the chartDiv.
 chartDiv.innerHTML = 'Cannot show elevation: request failed because ' +
    status;
    return;
}

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
data.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
}


chart.draw(data, {
  height: 200,
  legend: 'none',
  titleY: 'Elevation (m)'
 });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have looks like it should work...
Would need to see where `drawchart2` is called, the HTML elements, and any other code to be sure...

In this example, I add callback function `drawcharts` to start drawing...

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], 'callback': drawcharts});

function drawcharts() {
  drawchart();
  drawchart2();
}

function drawchart() {
  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Arm');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Weight');


  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    chartData.addRow([
      parseFloat(i),
      parseFloat(i * 1.5)
    ]);
  };


  var options = {
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Arm C.G',
      gridlines: {
        count: 10
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Weight',
      gridlines: {
        count: 10
      }
    },
    chartArea: {top:40, width: "70%", height: "75%"},
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true,
    },
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    pointSize: 5
  };

  myLineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1'));
  myLineChart.draw(chartData, options);
}

function drawchart2(elevations, status) {
  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('elevation_chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartDiv);
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data.addRow([
      '',
      i * 100
    ]);
  }

  chart.draw(data, {
    height: 200,
    legend: 'none',
    titleY: 'Elevation (m)'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="elevation_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just tried your code and it doesn't seem to work on my page which means it must be, as you say, something other than my js code that is causing the issue.

Comment: are you still getting two column charts? can you share all the code?

Comment: my mistake, I hadn't implemented your code correctly. It works fine now :) Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!